# I can't ssh to remote server on only one wireless network

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-10.04

I am having problems trying to ssh to a remote server from my wireless at work.

I tried removing the .ssh folder and such but I can't make it work. At first, I found it was a wireless driver problem in Ubuntu 10.04, but after that I could access from home.

These are all the facts I could gather.

- If I do a failed login it immediately answers me. If I enter the correct password it just hangs forever.
- I can do ssh from my wireless at home
- Co-workers can do ssh from the same wireless I cannot (They also have Ubuntu 10.04)

EDIT: Output after logging in. After printing this it just hangs there.

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
```

And this is my `ssh_config`

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

EDIT 2: auth.log data

```
Dec 13 16:56:26 sshd: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for MY_IP failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Dec 13 16:56:32 sshd: Accepted password for MY_USER from MY_IP port SOME_PORT ssh2
Dec 13 16:56:32 sshd: pam_env(sshd:setcred): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Dec 13 16:56:32 sshd: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user MY_USER
Dec 13 16:56:32 sshd: pam_env(sshd:setcred): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
```

I guess the `POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT` is the issue

Comment: Post the output of `ssh -v user@host`.

Comment: You can also try `tcpdump` to check for outgoing and incoming packets.

Comment: sounds an awful lot like (reverse) DNS issues. Anything in /var/log/auth.log?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a mis-configured firewall interfering with TCP windows.  This is pretty rare these days but leads to similar behavior.  You don't mention what OS your coworkers are using.  Linux is more sensitive to broken firewalls than other OSes in my experience.

I can't remember which options to disable, but try these as root:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_window_scaling
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps
```

That might fix it until the next reboot.  If it works you can add it to /etc/sysctl.conf to make it permanent, but it will lessen performance when sending big files.

Comment: It did not work. I updated the answer, they use the same OS (Ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: Try setting "UseDNS no" in sshd_config. Again, not sure it will help.